# how to give email validation to textbox in gridview in C# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

how to give email validation to textbox in gridview in asp.net

I Have gridview and in that i have textbox for email and i want to give email validation to that textbox on save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex sample

```
bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(emailString, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

or

.Net.Mail sample

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try {
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```